# SharePoint::SOAPHandler perl script works for display not copy

Tags: perl

I'm trying to copy files from a linux server to a sharepoint. I've got the connection working on the display of the sharepoint. There is 1 file out there to view. But I get a `401 Unauthorized` on the copy. Why would I be successful on the display but not the copy?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Authen::NTLM qw(ntlmv2);
use Data::Dumper;
use SharePoint::SOAPHandler;
use CopyTree::VendorProof;
use CopyTree::VendorProof::LocalFileOp;

delete $ENV{'https_proxy'};

my $sharepointobj = SharePoint::SOAPHandler ->new;
my $localfileobj = CopyTree::VendorProof::LocalFileOp ->new;

$sharepointobj->sp_creds_domain('operations.web.myworksite.com:443');
$sharepointobj->sp_creds_user('MYDOMAIN\myuserid');
$sharepointobj->sp_creds_password('Mypassword');
$sharepointobj->sp_authorizedroot('https://operations.web.myworksite.com:443/sites/CA...');

my $cpobj = CopyTree::VendorProof ->new;

print Dumper $sharepointobj->fdls('', 'Shared Documents');

$cpobj -> src('/opt/app/Reports/Excel/Reports_TABS1007.xlsx', $localfileobj);
$cpobj -> dst('Shared Documents/Reports_TABS1007.xlsx', $sharepointobj);
$cpobj -> cp;

print Dumper $sharepointobj->fdls('', 'Shared Documents');
```

Response:

> `$VAR1 = 'Shared Documents/Reports_TABS1006.xlsx';`
>   `$VAR2 = 'Shared Documents/Forms';`
>   `401 Unauthorized at /opt/app/perl/lib/perl5/SharePoint/SOAPHandler.pm line 374.`

Comment: "Why would I be successful on the display but not the copy?" Sounds like you don't have write access to the destination.

Comment: I do have write access, as I can place files onto the sharepoint. I mapped a drive of the sharepoint on my windows machine and have the write access.

Answer (score -1):

So I don't know if you got your answer, but -

There's a bug in NTLM.pm... To fix it, edit NTLM.pm and find the line:

```
$domain = substr($challenge, $c_info->{domain}{offset}, $c_info->{domain}{len});
```

and replace that code with:

```
$domain = &unicode($domain);
```

Comment: As of version 1.04 of `Authen::NTLM` you do not have to do this, just enable v2 of the protocol: `use Authen::HTML qw/ntlmv2/;`